# Selecting values from different views within a view

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume CAR1 and CAR2 are tables. Then I can do this:

```
select c1.modelType, c2.modelType from CAR1 c1, CAR2 c2;
```

Now assume that we have a view for CAR1 called V_CAR1, and a view for CAR2, V_CAR2.

Semilar, I want to select from the 2 views. Something like this:

```
select v_c1.NAME, v_c2.Type from V_CAR1 v_c1, V_CAR2 v_c2;
```

I can't do this, my sqqldeveloper just works forever, without coming up with an answer. I will also need to create a view, that will have to pull values from another view. I guess the problem will be the same. What am I doing wrong?

I am using Oracle

Comment: Are you using Oracle? Why no join conditions?

Comment: I'm still pretty new to Databases, so I have not much experience. I will try check up on it

Comment: Your query will give you a `CROSS JOIN` if you write it like this, which is going to generate all possible combinations of `c1.modelType` with `c2.modelType`. That could turn out to be a lot of rows to generate and return and it is most likely the reason why it takes so long for the data to be returned.

Comment: It makes sense why it take so long then, since there is no error in my query. Thanks, I need to work on the joins it seems, and add some constrains

Comment: Also, don't expect that selecting from views will work as fast as selecting from base tables. It depends on what the views are. A view can be as simple as "select everything from one table" but that is pretty much pointless; views often contain multiple joins and other expensive operations, and just calculating the view may take a long time, never mind joining two views the way you show in your question.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, your statement has no joins.

You can read about joins here; http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

An example of an inner join would be; I want to know the car Make/Model associated to each person.

My personel information is within one table and the car information is within another.

The 2 tables have 2 columns in common, which I can join to give me what i want; ref and subref

Tables;

V_CAR1 v_c1 ;

```
Name | Surname | Ref | Subref
John   Doe       100   1   
John   Smith     100   2  
Jim    Doe       200   1  
Jim    Smith     200   2
```

V_CAR2 v_c2;

```
Ref | Subref | Make   | Model
100   1        Nissan   Sunny 
100   2        Ford     Focus
200   1        Honda    Civic
200   2        Fiat     500
```

An example statement would be;

```
SELECT v_c1.Name, v_c1.Surname, v_c2.Make, v_c2.Model 
FROM VCAR1 v_c1
INNER JOIN VCAR2 v_c2
on (v_c1.ref = v_c2.ref and v_c1.subref = v_c2.subref)
```

This would give;

```
Name | Surname | Make   | Model
John  Doe       Nissan   Sunny 
John  Smith     Ford     Focus
Jim   Doe       Honda    Civic
Jim   Smith     Fiat     500
```

Hopefully this will assist you with getting started.

Comment: I chose inner join as it's probably the more commonly used one and a good starting point.

Comment: @Mor_snow does this help at all?

Comment: @MOR_SNOW correction*for some reason, I can't edit my previous comment.